# Codeigniter and Apache configuration issues

Tags: php, mysql, apache, codeigniter, server-configuration

I am having one Codeigniter project that include one "time expensive" synchronization. Basically I am connecting to remote server(running probably CentOS but thats all I know) via OCI8 to Oracle database, picking about 20,000 rows, and then updating local MySQL database.

That synchronization lasts for about 20ihs minutes (yes, MySQL could be more optimized and what not), but thats not the issue that I am having currently...

I have dedicated server with dual Xeon and 16 Gig of ram, CentOS x64, Apache 2.2.15, PHP 5.6.21 and MySQL version 5.6.30.

Now, with Apache 2 Handler and default PREFORK MPM, that synchronization works as intended.

If I leave Apache 2 Handler (mod_php I presume) and change MPM to WORKER or EVENT, that synchronization starts and PHP spits out white screen of death with nothing in log files.

If I switch to fcgi and EVENT or WORKER MPM, synchronization starts, and after about 2 minutes it gives me "The gateway did not receive a timely response from the upstream server or application."

Mind you that its not connection between servers issue since the moment I switch back to Apache 2.0 Handler and PREFORK it works as intended.

Codeigniter version is 2.1.0 (yes I am aware that it long past time to upgrade, its just inherited project and I am not fully aware if there has been some changes with CORE files and the guy is "well its working, ain't it".

Any clue or link with similar issue is more than appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: i'm really curious why do you want to switch from Prefork - which is working - to another ? I mean it doesn't explain why this works and the other doesn't ...

Comment: Because I am running SSL site, and from what I have read here as accepted answer it should be pretty much ok thing to do http://serverfault.com/questions/383526/how-do-i-select-which-apache-mpm-to-use
Also because Prefork MPM uses multiple child processes with one thread each and each process handles one connection at a time.

Worker MPM uses multiple child processes with many threads each. Each thread handles one connection at a time. It should be easier on RAM since it will spawn new process on request...
All based from what I have read online

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a `httpd -M` and see if you have `fcgid_module` in the list of Apache's active modules.

If not, do `yum install mod_fcgid` and install it

Then you will probably need to do some settings for your timeout issue, assuming you have set up everything else to use CGI/FastCGI instead of Apache 2 Handler, in your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` something like

```
<IfModule mod_fcgid.c>
        FcgidIdleTimeout 1800
        FcgidProcessLifeTime 1800
        FcgidBusyTimeout 1800
        FcgidIOTimeout 1800
        FcgidConnectTimeout 20
</IfModule>
```

Do a restart `service httpd restart` and `service php-fpm` restart (or whatever PHP handler you are using) and re-try

Comment: Thanks! That was the issue, it worked as soon as I installed fcgid_module.

Answer (score 0):

@Kosta, it looks like you are having some kind of server long request timeout error. I can't say what exactly for sure without checking logs. I also advice you to check PHP configuration Timeouts, max_execution_time, max_input_time it could also affect such problems.

Comment: Thanks for heads up, and for dignity to reply instead of just downvote, since I did tried to google what might be the issue. max_execution is set on 2000 and input on 1600 which is way more than 2 mins after which I get error but as said only with something other than mod_php and prefork... mod_php and other MPM give me white screen with nothing noticable in error logs...

Comment: It looks you should at list make both PHP equal max_execution and max_input_time to 2000. I think then you switch to mod_php and other MPM you are getting web server timeout. You should also check if web server timeouts can be increased to the same value as you have on mod_php and prefork.

Comment: I might not be clear enough...
1. mod_php + prefork = works as intended
2. mod_php + worker/event = white screen of death
3. fcgi + any mpm = 504 timeout...
Anyway thanks again I will try fiddling with timeouts then
Cheers